# How to Stub a DOM object with AngularJs and/or Sinon

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

I'm trying to test an angular controller that queries the DOM for a select box value.

```
$scope.getValue = function(){
   document.getElementById('select_box_value').value;
}
```

How can I stub this function so it returns a simple integer value in a controller test, like so? Every time I try it this way, the original function runs instead of my stub.

```
describe('MyCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
            '$scope': scope,
            '$scope.getValue':sinon.stub().returns(20)
        });
    }));
    it('gets the select box value', function () {
        expect(scope.getValue).toBe(20);
    });

});
```

Comment: Angular controllers shouldn't interact with the DOM directly, only directives should be accessing or modifying the DOM and are used in the view.  Not sure about the test issue though.

Comment: The likes of `document.getElementById('select_box_value').value;`  should never be used in Angular - at all. You simply need to (in a lot of cases) add `ng-model` to your html element and then access that model in the $scope. In this case, you're trying to perhaps test against something that doesn't exist (hence you should never interact directly with the DOM in a controller)